# spring 3.2 testing the requestmappings are there and working, but the java is not invoked

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-test

All my mappings are working correctly :

```
 MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/company/doSomething"))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();
```

returns status ok from this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/company/doSomething", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean myMethod() {
      return false;
    }
```

if I set a breakpoint in the controller method, and run test n debug mode the test just passes (the breakpoint is not invoked) and prints out the responses - nothing is returned and I get this :

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 200
       Error message = null
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = default
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

and the actual request looks like this

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = GET
         Request URI = /company/doSomething
          Parameters = {}
             Headers = {}

             Handler:
                Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler
```

Comment: Can you give anymore detail? What is your expected result and does it give anything other than that MockHttpServletResponse?

Comment: @sparks It should print `false` to the response body.

Comment: You may want to try not returning a primitive data type. I have encountered errors before where spring didn't like them. Make `public boolean myMethod()` into `public Boolean myMethod()`.

Comment: I think you need to add `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` to the existing `@RequestMapping` annotation to indicate the type of content that will be returned.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis no luck, see edit

Comment: @sparks no dice see edit

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you return `true`? Maybe `false` is handled as `null`. Also doesn't a MockHttpServletResponse have an `OutputStream`? Check that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis when I set a breakpoint in controller method and run test in debug mode, nothing happens. The java is simply not being invoked ... seomthing wrong in my set up I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the actual handler selected (i.e. DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler) I can see that no annotated controller method matched. Somehow the request as specified does not match the controller method request mapping.

Comment: shouldn't that return a 404 instead then ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the @Controller annotation on your class?

Also do you have the Jackson2 (JSON) libraries in your classpath?

When I copy your code and run the tests, I get the correct response output:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 200
   Error message = null
         Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}
    Content type = application/json
            Body = false
   Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

**However** my request output states the correct handler

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
     HTTP Method = GET
     Request URI = /company/doSomething
      Parameters = {}
         Headers = {}
         Handler:
            Type = example.TestController
          Method = public java.lang.Boolean example.TestController.myMethod()
```

whereas your output states that the default DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler handler is handling the request.